# Problem with reputation on Area 51

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I confirmed my email and I got 50 reputation points. I added a question to "Guitar" community and it was voted as "not good example". Anyway now I have 49 points and I CAN'T VOTE ANYMORE.

What should be done to gain reputation?

Comment: Check out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58402/doesnt-the-rep-requirement-for-voting-on-area51-overly-punish-new-users-with-a-s. Aarobot's answer specifies what you yourself can do - flag a moderator to recalculate your reputation after you delete the example question.

Answer (score 1):

Post some more questions. These will get votes and quickly push you above the limit.

Comment: You should mean "Post some *good* questions"

Comment: No - bad ones are often off topic. =:-)